# What should do to generate a minimal Linux kernel?

Tags: linux-kernel, configuration, memory

I am working on an embedded Linux system (5.10.24), and now I want to check what is the minimal kernel I can build, so with lots of playing of kernel configurations, now I have following kernel.

```
# dmesg | grep 'Memory:'
Memory: 12620K/16384K available (1933K kernel code, 128K rwdata, 236K rodata, 192K init, 55K bss, 3764K reserved, 0K cma-reserved)

# free
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          12812        2624        8808           0        1380        8928
Swap:             0           0           0
```

I have disabled some critical kernel codes like `sysfs` and drivers.
So currently, I cannot optimization in kernel configuration to decrease the kernel memory usage.

This is normal kernel and running on MPU with MMU, for now I may not turn to uCLinux.

Next, I may change the code manually, by disabling or simplifying the kernel codes.  But before I do that, I firstly want to narrow down the kernel features which are using more memory than others.

So is there any advice which codes should I focus on firstly? And is there any tool to help me figure out which part of kernel takes more memory which I should pay attention to?

Comment: Consult with OpenWRT.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out my way to generate a minimal Linux kernel.
Here it is.

1. Follow the normal and common way to run `make menuconfig` to go through tons of configurations and disable what is NOT used/needed, this is the `risk-less` way.
   Remember to build and boot the kernel to check if the change is working as expected.
2. Disable kernel components which take memory alot, such as `sysfs`, `procfs` and `printk`. This change will decrease the kernel footprint alot, but which may stop some feature from working, such as `free`, `ps`, `mount` which are heavily relying on `procfs`. So this is the tradeoff of memory size and functions.
3. Customize kernel parameters from bootloader, to disable or set some kernel features to use less memory.
4. with `readelf` to check which functions and data are taking memory. changing the kernel codes, to simplify some functions based on specific hardware platform, such as the number of IRQs, etc.

It is necessary to build and test the kernel image after each change.

With trials and tests, finally I get the kernel image as follows,

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 t    t      972961 Nov 29 22:09 vmlinuz

text    data     bss     dec     hex
1860928  242232   28032 2131192  2084f8

# free
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           5620        2140        2188           0        1292        2660
Swap:             0           0           0
```

#### With sh disabled

According to paladin's comment, I tried to disable 'sh' in kernel and compared the result.

Before change.

```
text    data     bss     dec     hex
7905846 1791740  135872 9833458  960bf2
```

After change

```
text    data     bss     dec     hex
7905026 1787608  135872 9828506  95f89a
```

So there are about 800Bytes saved in `text` and about 3KB in `data`.

Comment: You can remove most of the kernel debug console output, but it makes error debugging a mess. You can remove the kernel modules option, but you need to include all needed modules into kernel. You can remove support for shell-script-executables (*.sh) from kernel, but when doing so, you need to replace ALL shell-scripts with compiled programs which run before userspace is loaded until your system finally runs in userspace (I really don't recommend this, but it'll save a lot of memory.).

Comment: PS this also means your init system must be a compiled executable, C example: `#include <stdlib.h>; int main(){system("/bin/sh /etc/init.sh"); return 0;}`

Comment: I did try the `init` with my compiled executable, which open `/proc/meminfo` and out put the memory info to the `/dev/ttyS0`. So I did not totally remove the `procfs` and `tty` driver, both of them take lot of memory. I can try your advice of "remove support for shell-script from kernel' to get a smaller kernel. In fact, removing `printk` did save lot of memory, but as you said it cause debugging more diffcult. So it should be kept during development and be disabled in production.

Comment: PS you also could use very old kernels, if your embedded device doesn't need network conectivity but just a UART, it's possible to reduce kernel size to less than 1 MiB > https://superuser.com/questions/130457/what-linux-fits-on-a-floppy-disk

Comment: Yep, I cannot agree more with you! I had this idea but finally I gave it up. Because this kernel is from a SOC vendor, who has added UART driver, LCD driver based on its SOC architecture, changing the kernel is impossible without their support. I bookmarked the link you recommended, and will use it once possible.

Comment: Check this link: https://archive.kernel.org/oldlinux/ it's an Archive with various old Linux stuff, most arranged/composed (but not original created) by a chinese author named Jiong Zhao. Most original documents are in english, supported by his chinese book. Maybe you can read chinese, but I think it's also helpful if you cannot read chinese, just look into the directories/files.

Comment: Interesting, I thought disabling `sh` would give a lot more of free space. I was wrong in believing there is a copy of the sh-interpreter inbuilt into kernel.  Good to know.